# Regex for empty space

Tags: php, regex

I am using this regex: `preg_match('~[^A-Za-z0-9\+\-"]~', $incoming);`
How can I add empty spaces here?

An example:

```
word1 word2
```

I mean the space between word1 and word2. I want to allow only one space. Not like `word1  word2` (there are two spaces between these words).
But `word1 word2 word3` shall be allowed. 
Is that possible?

This is my current function:

```
$incoming = '"test test test"';
$forbidden_chars = preg_match('~[^A-Za-z0-9\+\-"\s]~', $incoming);


if( /*$string_length < 150 &&*/ !$forbidden_chars){
    $valid_query = TRUE;    
}
else{
    $valid_query = FALSE;
}
```

`$valid_query` should be true, but it is still false.
Why?

All examples:

`"test"` `test` `+test` `-test` `test test` `"test test"` shall be allowed, this shall also be possible `test test test` this not: `test  test` (2 Spaces between the words)

Comment: What's an empty space? Do you mean an empty string?

Comment: Do you want to match empty spaces, or not match them? Where is "here?" — in the character class?

Comment: Oh. Are you trying to match as many words as possible that are separated by a single space?

Comment: Can you give some more examples and what should and shouldn't match?

Comment: Best to give a list of examples, explain which matches and which don't match (and the whys).

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie  I did. Please have a look at the original post. I added the example on bottom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to match the following:

- Leading single space, optionally
- A word
- Trailing single space, optionally
- One or more times

Try this:

```
^ ?(\w+ ?)+$
```

EDIT 1:

Based on what I could figure out from your examples, here's what you need:

```
^ ?(?:[\w"+-]+ ?)+$
```

This will match 1 or more "words" that are single space separated. This allows optional leading and trailing single space.

Comment: Strings like `"test"` `test` `+test` `-test` `test test` `"test test"` shall be allowed thsi shall also be possible `test test test` (2 ore more space) but NOT `test  test` (2 space following directly)

Comment: Can you put these examples in your original post? I'd like to "edit" so I can see where the spaces are. I don't see an example where there is a leading space. Is that right? What about trailing spaces?

Comment: like this: `preg_match('[^ ?(?:[\w"+-]+ ?)+$]', $incoming);` correct? It seems to work. :) Thanks a lot for your patience!

Answer (score 1):

try below

```
preg_match('~[^A-Za-z0-9\+\s\-"]~', $incoming);
```

Comment: I got this error `Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: range out of order in character class at offset 19`

Answer (score 0):

Just put a space inside the square brackets.

Answer (score 0):

you should simply handle this (removing duplicated space) within your method whatever input is, just simply prepare input before processing as following

```
$incoming= ereg_replace(' +', ' ', $incoming);
```